# vm.$on undefined error in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am following this best practice style guide for angular development and I can't seem to get this one part working cleanly.

Best Practice Style Guide:
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

It recommends to declare controllers by the following:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('feedController', FeedController);

function feedController(){
   var vm = this; //My $scope variable
}
```

The problem is I am trying to use `$on` to add an event listener but it gives me an undefined error for `vm.$on`. A temporary solution I found was to inject $scope into the controller by the following:

```
FeedController.$inject = ['apiservice', '$scope'];
```

and call `$scope.$on` which works but I feel its inconsistent now. Is there a way to still use vm in a clean way.

You can see the full controller here https://github.com/bliitzkrieg/TrailerFeed/blob/master/app/components/feed/FeedController.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this`/`vm` refers to the *instance of the controller*, not the scope that is associated with that controller.

Events only exist on scopes, so to use the event system it is correct to inject `$scope` to get a reference to the controller's scope where `$on` is available.

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('feedController', FeedController);

function feedController($scope){
   var vm = this; // the instance of the controller
   $scope.on(...) // the controller's scope
}
```